# Running macro to specific style

Tags: vba, ms-word, styles

Below code is trying to convert words in lowercase in to uppercase. However I only need to run it only in a specific word style ("Normal"). I tried to set doc to ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal") but i keep on getting error. Any help would be most helpful. Thank you in advance.

```
Option Explicit

   Public Sub TitleCaseDocument()
   Dim doc As Document: Set doc = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
   Dim wrd As Range

   For Each wrd In doc.Words
       If wrd.Text <> UCase$(wrd.Text) Then wrd.Case = wdTitleWord
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided by @eaazel falls into the default member trap.

The code

```
wrd.Style
```

is in reality using the default member of the style object, which is 'NameLocal'.  Thus the code implied by the code above is in reality

```
wrd.Style.NameLocal
```

Normally this would not be a problem, however, the level of granularity that is being used to extract the style object means that,  on occasion, words with no style will be encountered (e.g. a ToC field).  In such a case the style object returned is nothing and this generates a surprising error because you cannot call the NameLocal method on an an object that is nothing.

Therefore a more correct approach is to use a word unit that is guaranteed to have a style object (e.g. paragraphs) and to test for the style on this object before testing each word.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TitleCaseDocument()
    Dim myDoc As Document: Set myDoc = ActiveDocument

    Dim myPara As Range
    For Each myPara In myDoc.StoryRanges.Item(wdMainTextStory).Paragraphs

        If myPara.Style.NameLocal = "Normal" Then

            TitleParagraph myPara

       End If

    Next

End Sub

Public Sub TitleParagraph(ByVal ipRange As Word.Range)

    Dim myText As Range
    For Each myText In ipRange.Words

        If Not UCase$(myText.Text) = myText.Text Then

            myText.Words.Item(1).Case = wdTitleWord

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Update 2020-Apr-16 Revised code below which has been proved to work on a Word document.

Option Explicit

```
Public Sub TitleCaseDocument()
    Dim myDoc As Document: Set myDoc = ActiveDocument

    Dim myPara As Word.Paragraph
    For Each myPara In myDoc.StoryRanges.Item(wdMainTextStory).Paragraphs

        If myPara.Style.NameLocal = "Normal" Then

            TitleParagraph myPara

       End If

    Next

End Sub

Public Sub TitleParagraph(ByVal ipPara As Word.Paragraph)

    Dim myText As Range
    For Each myText In ipPara.Range.Words

        If Not UCase$(myText.Text) = myText.Text Then

            myText.Words.Item(1).Case = wdTitleWord

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response. However I encountered "Type mismatch" error upon running the code above in the `For Each` loop. Not sure how to fix this

Comment: Thank you so much. Updated code above works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

So Do You want to change lowercase in to uppercase if style is normal?
Yes?
I don't have big experience with word but maybe something like this help you (base on your code):

```
Public Sub TitleCaseDocument()
   Dim doc As Document: Set doc = ActiveDocument
   Dim wrd As Range

   For Each wrd In doc.Words

       If wrd.Text <> UCase$(wrd.Text) And wrd.Style = "Normal" Then
       wrd.Text = UCase$(wrd.Text)

       End If
Next
End Sub
```